# Unable to save bookmarks in Edge

Tags: browser, bookmarks, microsoft-edge, favorites

I was having trouble importing my favorites, when a friend of mine found a thread here on superuser and somehow managed to make it so I cannot add or import bookmarks at all; when I try to, it simply does nothing.  Where do I even begin to fix this?

The article he referenced: [Add Bookmarks to Microsoft Edge manually](https://superuser.com/questions/1002351/add-bookmarks-to-microsoft-edge-manually/1014554)

OS: Widows 10 Home 64-bit

Browser having the issue: Edge 25.10586.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the imports and adds are working properly... but you're looking at the wrong place for your favorites?

Favorites are found via the "hub" icon (the icon 3 little lines) then the "star" icon

[image]