# Import IE Favorites to Win 10 Edge from a COPY of the IE Favorites FOLDER

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, import, microsoft-edge

I just did a fresh install of Win 10, following an irrecoverable crash of Win 7. Because of the crash, all of my IE Favorites were lost, so there is nothing in that location to "import."

However, I had thoroughly backed up my drive, so I DO have a copy of the IE "Favorites" FOLDER, including all of the sub-folders and Internet Shortcut files. There seems to be no way to "point" Edge toward this folder, and the only workarounds I've seen so far involve running arcane commands and editing registry files. Is there no easier way?

As of now, my IE "Favorites" file is sitting on the desktop of my newly updated Windows 10 machine, but I cannot find any way to connect the two. In case it matters, I have yet to bookmark anything in Edge, so I would not care if I had to wipe out the current list of default favorites.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just copy the contents in your new profile's Favorites directory

Comment: I found a partial workaround. If I dump all of my Favorites into the folder Edge seems to be importing, I can import all of the FOLDERS, but none of the contents. Then I can visit and add Favorites . . . one at a time. Has Microsoft learned NOTHING since v. 3?

Comment: Ramhound, that does not work. I tried. My new profile does not seem to have a Favorite folder.

Comment: So start IE11, add a single favorite, the copy the contents from your backup to that folder.  I know this works because I have done it in the past

Comment: As best I understand, I have tried this three times now, without any success. I don't understand why this has to be so difficult. The windows model has a perfect mechanism for organizing hierarchies - Windows and Folders. Why can't favorites simply be organized in this fashion? It was possible, albeit cumbersome with older versions of IE, but Microsoft seems to have engineered the last vestige of user-friendliness out of this, just as it does with everything else in Windows. I know how MS can make a quantum leap forward - license Apple OS 1 (1984) and put WX in the trash where it belongs!

Comment: Favorites folder within the profile folder is the location for IE11 favorites, and it is a folder, [Edge is a different beast but there is still a folder.](http://superuser.com/questions/998862/win10-edge-favorites-folder-location).  More [information](http://superuser.com/questions/1002351/add-bookmarks-to-microsoft-edge-manually/1002377#1002377)

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but your link was what drove me here in the first place. It goes 8 layers deep in folders to two separate locations, and requires running .bat files and editing the registry. This is absolutely ABSURD for the simple task of moving user favorites between versions of THE SAME COMPANY'S software. And the process of organizing / managing favorites, once you have them finally attached to Edge, is worse than the command-line days. Why can't MS design an OS or an App to do the simplest, most obvious things?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why Edge isn't importing your favorites after they have been copied to the correct location for IE.

However, there is a 3rd-party application called EdgeMange that you can try.  It might be able to read the folders where they are.

PS: I am the author of EdgeManage

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

Comment: Note that [disclosure is required](http://superuser.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Why is a third-party application even required.  How software should be recommended is outlined in the help center.

Comment: "Why is a third-party application even required" - Because using the built-in features of Edge obviously isn't working for this poster.   I don't see anything about "how software should be recommended" in the Help Center, can you help